# Access through samba to link to different filesystem in shared directory (permission error)

Tags: permissions, windows, samba, symlink, lubuntu

I have a laptop with Dual Boot Lubuntu 14.04/Windows 7

I have a `BorrajaX` user in Lubuntu and another `Borrajax` user in Windows.

In my Lubuntu `$HOME/Documents/` directory I created a link to the Windows `BorrajaX` user's documents, so I can store things there when in Linux and retrieve them when in Windows, and viceversa.

In Lubuntu, the directory structure is:

```
/home/borrajax/    drwxr-xr-x  borrajax borrajax
  |-> Downloads/     drwxr-xr-x  borrajax borrajax            
  |-> Documents/     drwxr-xr-x  borrajax borrajax
  |     |-> TestDir/    drwxrwxr-x borrajax borrajax
  |     |-> Windows7_Documents -> /media/windows7/Documents and Settings/borrajax/Documents/    lrwxrwxrwx  borrajax borrajax
  |           |-> Android Things/  drwxrwxr--  root  plugdev
  |           |-> desktop.ini      -rwxrwxr--  root  plugdev
  |           |-> My Pictures -> /media/windows7/Users/borrajax/Pictures  lrwxrwxrwx root plugdev
  |-> Pictures/     drwxr-xr-x  borrajax borrajax
```

The link to `Windows7_Documents` is pointing to a directory in a different partition than where my `/home/borrajax` is mounted (my `$HOME` is on `/dev/sda5` while the Windows 7 partition is `/dev/sda3`)

Everything works fine when I access the Windows filesystem locally through that `Windows7_Documents` link, but now I want to share my Linux `$HOME`, being able to access that `Windows7_Documents` remotely, and (here's the issue) I can't. I get a `Permission Denied` error.

This is how my shared `$HOME/Documents/` directory shows on a Mac OS X that is accessing it through Samba:

[image]

From the Mac Os X I can properly create new files or directories within my Lubuntu's `$HOME/Documents/`, but I can't access the link in `$HOME/Documents/Windows7_Documents/`

Below is the configuration of the Samba share in Lubuntu's config file (`/etc/samba/smb.conf`):

```
[borrajax]
    path = /home/borrajax
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
    valid users = borrajax
    hosts allow = 192.168.1. 127.0.0.1
```

Is there a way to access the `Windows7_Documents` directory through samba? I suspect it might have something to do with all the files within the `Windows7_Documents` belonging to `root:plugdev` ? But if that's the case, how could I make the Samba users belong to the `plugdev` group (which I guess it would be the best solution? )

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put following lines into your smb.conf:

```
    follow symlinks = yes
    wide links = yes
```

It seems that Samba does not follow symlinks by default.

Comment: I also added `unix extensions = no`, as described here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1439092 I think without it it wouldn't work? Although I'm not sure whether I had restarted every samba service/connection from my Mac OS X properly, though (maybe it was that)

Comment: Thanks BorrajaX, this `unix extensions = no` has to be in the [global] section, the other ones i.e. `follow symlinks = yes` and `wide links = yes` in the directory section, here `[borrajax]`